# JIRA: Get Description Of Epic & All Issues Under Epic Level Using REST APIs

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get the Epic description text plus all the user stories/bugs etc under an EPIC programmatically.

In terms of getting the EPIC user stories/bugs I see 2 options

```
https://jira2.companyname.com/rest/agile/1.0/epic/TestProject-1408/issue

https://jira2.companyname.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=%22Epic%20Link%22%20=TestProject-1408
```

I'd rather option 2 as I'm using API v2 plus I can add more filters to the search if need be.

I get the description of the EPIC using this API

```
https://jira2.companyname.com/rest/api/2/issue/TestProject-1408?fields=description
```

My question is can I combine both APIs to return the description of the EPIC plus all the user stories/bugs etc so that I'm only querying JIRA once rather than twice. Reason for wanting to do this is we have a good number of EPICs within our projects so i'd prefer making one API call rather than two if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The search endpoint returns descriptions, why isn't that sufficient?

Comment: You can search like: "Epic Link" = TestProject-1408 OR key=TestProject-1408, then search results will contain all the issues or epic plus your epic with description.

Comment: hey that's super thx a mill for your help with this :)

Comment: do you mean this https://jira2.companyname.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=%22Epic%20Link%22%20=TestProject-1408 that does not include description of the epic